# Starknet/Cairo function (long)string parameter

Tags: string, deserialization, starknet, cairo-lang

Some internals of Starknet expect some `string` as the parameter.

> error: Plugin diagnostic: `selector` macro argument must be a string

When heaving inputs serialized into type, which has property of `felt252` for shortString (which should be enough) I'm struggling to find way of converting shortString into expected `string` here.

Q1: What type of the property for `selector!()` can I specify to make it properly work?

Q2: If above is not possible - is there a way of selecting contract ABI for `call_contract_syscall()`'s parameter from `felt252` string?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out `starknet::call_contract_syscall()`'s second parameter IS indeed `felt252` and the macro `selector!()` transforms "string" into felt252 shortString. So the answer to my Q2 is to use shortString directly. Q1 is still remain if anyone's looking for that...

Comment: if someone gets here with some confusions: `'contract_method_name'` (as felt252 "short" string) is not equal to `selector!("contract_method_name")`